# Python-Requests Scraping YouTube description with BS4 issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, siblings

I'm trying to get both the text and the links as shown in the picture. But I can only get the text via siblings and the links after. I need them to come together like in the image. I tried using br.next_element but it doesn't grab the a-links. What am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_id = 'aM7aW0G58CI'

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+url_id)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for i in soup.find_all('p', id='eow-description'):
    for br in i.find_all('br'):
        next_sib = br.next_sibling
        print(next_sib)

for i in soup.find_all('p', id='eow-description'):
    for a in i.find_all('a'):
        print(a.text)
```

This is the output that I am getting. I'm not getting what the screenshot below shows.

OutPut:

```
Special shout to 
Wanna support what we do? Livestream at 2PM PT!: 
It Wasn’t Me, I Swear!: 
TheDeFrancoFam Vlog: 
———————————— 
CATCH UP ON THIS WEEK’S SHOWS: 
<br/>
Why People Are Freaking Out About The Trump NFL Boycott and Anthony Weiner Going to Jail…: 
WOW! Dirty Advertising Exposed And Major Backlash Following Unexpected Compromise…: 
Why Trump's "HUGE Failure" Is A Massive Loss For His Enemies and A Shocking Change To Women's Rights: 
DISGUSTING! The Horrible Truth About Belle Gibson Exposed, Controversial Video Blows Up, and More: 
<br/>
————————————
GET SOME GEAR: 
————————————
FACEBOOK: 
TWITTER: 
INSTAGRAM: 
SNAPCHAT: TheDeFrancoFam
REDDIT: 
ITUNES: 
GOOGLE PLAY: 
————————————
Edited by:
James Girardier - 
Jason Mayer - 
<br/>
Produced by:
Amanda Morones - 
<br/>
Motion Graphics Artist:
Brian Borst - 
<br/>
P.O. BOX
Attn: Philip DeFranco
16350 Ventura Blvd
Ste D #542
Encino, CA 91436
http://DKPhil.com
http://DeFrancoElite.com
https://youtu.be/fFxDbYE06zU
https://youtu.be/kR7DquGe4vY
https://youtu.be/qdWUQGHtyPk
https://youtu.be/CWlUs1-7KN4
https://youtu.be/kUWt-oipvOY
https://youtu.be/XVsTh4zxKNo
https://teespring.com/stores/defranco...
http://on.fb.me/mqpRW7
http://Twitter.com/PhillyD
https://instagram.com/phillydefranco/
https://www.reddit.com/r/DeFranco
http://DeFrancoMistakes.com
http://mistakeswithdefranco.com
https://twitter.com/jamesgirardier
https://www.instagram.com/jayjaymay/
https://twitter.com/MandaOhDang
https://twitter.com/brianjborst
```

[image]

Comment: Just for a little more clarity, Could you edit your question with what output you're getting currently?

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Yes, sure not a problem. Thank you for the constructive criticism.

Comment: can't you put all in one `for` loop ?

Comment: @furas I have but it doesn't change much. I just compartmentalized it for visual sake.Did you find an answer by combining the loop?

Comment: can you add `url_id` to check it ?

Comment: @furas Sorry, I missed that when copying it over to SE. Thanks! I'm merely scraping a youtube video for their description is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `children` and checking `tag` name (`child.name`) I made

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_id = 'aM7aW0G58CI'

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+url_id)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# to concatenate <br> 
br = ''

for p in soup.find_all('p', id='eow-description'):
    for child in p.children:
        if child.name == 'a':
            #print(' a:', child.text)
            print(br, child.text)
            br = '' # reset br
        elif child.name == 'br':
            if child.next_sibling.name != 'br': # skip <br/> ?
                #print('br:', child.next_sibling)
                br += str(child.next_sibling)
        #else:
        #    print(child.name, child)
```

I get:

```
Special shout to  http://DKPhil.com
Wanna support what we do? Livestream at 2PM PT!:  http://DeFrancoElite.com
It Wasn’t Me, I Swear!:  https://youtu.be/fFxDbYE06zU
TheDeFrancoFam Vlog:  https://youtu.be/kR7DquGe4vY
———————————— CATCH UP ON THIS WEEK’S SHOWS: Why People Are Freaking Out About The Trump NFL Boycott and Anthony Weiner Going to Jail…:  https://youtu.be/qdWUQGHtyPk
WOW! Dirty Advertising Exposed And Major Backlash Following Unexpected Compromise…:  https://youtu.be/CWlUs1-7KN4
Why Trump's "HUGE Failure" Is A Massive Loss For His Enemies and A Shocking Change To Women's Rights:  https://youtu.be/kUWt-oipvOY
DISGUSTING! The Horrible Truth About Belle Gibson Exposed, Controversial Video Blows Up, and More:  https://youtu.be/XVsTh4zxKNo
————————————GET SOME GEAR:  https://teespring.com/stores/defranco...
————————————FACEBOOK:  http://on.fb.me/mqpRW7
TWITTER:  http://Twitter.com/PhillyD
INSTAGRAM:  https://instagram.com/phillydefranco/
SNAPCHAT: TheDeFrancoFamREDDIT:  https://www.reddit.com/r/DeFranco
ITUNES:  http://DeFrancoMistakes.com
GOOGLE PLAY:  http://mistakeswithdefranco.com
————————————Edited by:James Girardier -  https://twitter.com/jamesgirardier
Jason Mayer -  https://www.instagram.com/jayjaymay/
Produced by:Amanda Morones -  https://twitter.com/MandaOhDang
Motion Graphics Artist:Brian Borst -  https://twitter.com/brianjborst
```

---

**EDIT:** you may have to use

```
else:
    print(child.name, child)
```

to get PO BOX address

Answer (score 1):

I found a really simple way:

```
for p in soup.find_all('p', id='eow-description'):
    print(p.get_text('\n'))
```

Only issue now is that some of the links are stripped with `...`

You can also play around with `youtube-dl` python module to get the description of a youtube video that way as well.

Comment: Hey thanks, @xninjaKittyx. Your solution is very simple and clean. I wonder why it strips? I didn't know about youtube-dl. It definitely looks useful!

Comment: Either the raw data itself is being stripped, or it has something to do with how <a> tags are being parsed by beautifulsoup/lxml

Answer (score 1):

I have found this way..

```
import pafy

url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aM7aW0G58CI'

vid=pafy.new(url)

print(vid.description)
```

By this method, you will get your content in the exact same way as shown in Youtube's video description.